# Angular5 element inside *ngif is allways undefined

Tags: angular5, angular-ng-if

In the following scenario, when I `click` the first `div` `childDiv` is always marked as `undefined` Because `methodB` returns `false`, if at some point `methodB` returns `true` and `childDiv` is rendered, when I click the first `div` again `childDiv` is still `undefined`.

```
<div (click)="someMethod(); childDiv.click()">
   ...
</div>

<div *ngIf="methodB()"
   <paper-chip #chip label="Hello">
     <span #spanChip>
        H
     </span>
   </paper-chip>
   <div id="childDiv" #childDiv (click)="chip.label='Bye'; spanChip.textContent='B''>
```

**What can I do so that if `methodB` returns true `childDiv` it is not `undefined`?**

Answer (score 0):

Why invoking childDiv click, when you can simply call its click method?

Try something like this:

```
<div (click)="someMethod(); if (methodB()) someOtherMethod()">
   <div *ngIf="methodB()" id="childDiv" #childDiv (click)="someOtherMethod()'</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right! I need to change my example to show the real problem